# Backbone events - disable Capture phase

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

Backbone events model seems to be available for both Capture as well as the Bubble phase.
I want to disable the triggering of events during capture phase and only be able to trigger/handle an event during the bubble phase.

Any pointer would be of great help

Comment: Can you be more specific on what are you trying to accomplish? maybe a use case?

Comment: I am trying to use the BB events hash for click event.

Let's say you have the hierarchy of Table --> Row --> Cell.
When a specific cell is clicked, I need to do something and stop the event propagation, so that the Table-click event handler is not triggered.

In current scenario, what I see is Table-click event-handler is triggered first and then the control goes to cell-click event-handler.
And if I do not stopPropagation in cell-click event handler, Table-click event handler is called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click table tr > td > a': function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
      /// do stuff
     }
  }
}):
```

Comment: I was using stopPropagation alone but with prevetDeafault it works fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Backbone does not impose an event detection mechanism on events.

### Backbone `.on()`

In fact, other than Backbone events which must be triggered manually, and are not attached to the DOM (doing something like myView.on('event-name', someCallback, view), and triggering with myView.trigger('eventName')), all the view DOM Events, which are defined by the events hash, are delegate to jQuery.

### Backbone.events

Take a look at the Backbone method that binds the events in the events hash, `delegateEvents`:

```
delegateEvents: function(events) {
  if (!(events || (events = _.result(this, 'events')))) return this;
  this.undelegateEvents();
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = events[key];
    if (!_.isFunction(method)) method = this[events[key]];
    if (!method) continue;

    var match = key.match(delegateEventSplitter);
    var eventName = match[1], selector = match[2];
    method = _.bind(method, this);
    eventName += '.delegateEvents' + this.cid;

    /*** (Seebiscuit Comment  ***
     * This is where the event is 
     * actually bound.        ***/
    if (selector === '') {
      this.$el.on(eventName, method); /* (Seebiscuit) Notice the jQuery */
    } else {
      this.$el.on(eventName, selector, method);
    }
  }
  return this;
}
```

From the jQuery man page on the `on` function:

> In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create consistent cross-browser behavior. [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you read further down the docs you'll see that jQuery chose, as most browsers do, to bubble events.

Now not all events bubble. The short list (from [Browser Events](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/09/06/browser-events-bubbling-capturing-and-delegation)):

- **change/submit/reset**: don't bubble in IE 6/7/8, but jQuery makes them bubble
- **focus/blur**: jQuery's uses `focusin`/`focusout` hacks to bubble focus/blur events
- **load/error/resize/readystatechange/...**: Methods on the window or on XHR objects not relevant to event delegation

But, since Backbone uses jQuery's event delegation, you're assured that even in the trickier cases you don't have to worry about event capturing propagation.

Comment: so should I consider this as a suggestion - to avoid using BB events hash and use .on

Comment: No, they're both different. The events hash binds DOM events to DOM elements under your view, and Backbone `.on()` can bind events to a Backbone object (see the first section of my Answer). Backbone objects are not DOM elements. Yet we can listen to events happening to them (as when someone calls `myBackboneObject.trigger("some:event")`), by using `.on()`.

Comment: The point of my Answer is to prove that the concept of event propagation does not apply to Backbone `.on()` since there are no object hierarchies to traverse and therefore do not propagate. Extension of Backbone, like Marionette do have children and parent views, and there view events bubble from the child to the parent.